# get user Active Directory details

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

I am building a simple intranet site and I want to get the user's Active Directory.

What steps do I need to take on the IIS side for this to work?
Are any changes required to my web config?

I would appreciate a detailed explanation, as this is giving me a hard time.

I have tryed things like this

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString
```

also

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

the users will not login the page should be able to get the credentials without them typing their username and password

windows authentication in my web config throws an error and causes my page not to work

Comment: A little more background information is needed I think. What do you mean by the "user's active directory"? Are you looking for their logon name, domain, some other information related to their user?

Comment: i am looking for the user name but if i get the domain\username id be happy with that

Comment: Is your site/IIS application using Windows Integrated Auth? If not those values will not work/will be empty. You're probably getting the error because you are using Windows Auth in the config but not setting the IIS application to use Windows Auth, you probably have anonymous.

Comment: i set my web site as an application in iis6. Then i also turned of annonymous, however now i must login for this to work, i do not want the user to be prompted to login

Comment: @MyHeadHurts So, you did set "Windows authenticaiton" and it does work.  The only thing that you don't like i s the prompt, right?  The prompt is actually from the browser.  If you are using IE, you need to make sure your site is a trusted site.  Then, IE won't prompt you to enter.

Comment: thats the thing, it is considered a trusted site with ie. There must be a setting i am forgeting in ii6

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good starting point for you:
[Recipe: Enabling Windows Authentication within an Intranet ASP.NET Web application](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx)

or this:
[Active Directory Services: PrincipalContext — What is the DN of a “container” object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538064/active-directory-services-principalcontext-what-is-the-dn-of-a-container-ob)

As @Joel Ehterton said, more details of exactly what you're trying to do would be helpful.