# Need to reset and expire a password in Active Directory within a PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory, passwords

I was trying to use the following code to set an Active Directory's user password:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
{
  using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName ))
  {
      user.SetPassword( "newpassword" );
      user.ExpirePasswordNow();
  }
}
```

The code pulled the user information with no problem, but I got an Access Denied when trying to reset the password.  I then realized that the above code provided no security context within which to do the operation.  How to put that in?  MSDN gives the full constructor for PrincipalContext as:

```
public PrincipalContext(
   ContextType contextType,
   string name,
   string container,
   string userName,
   string password
)
```

and all the examples I could find made it clear that the first string was the server name, and username and password were clear enough, too, but what was the "container".  The description in MSDN was as clear as mud:

> "The container on the store to use as the root of the context. All
>   queries are performed under this root, and all inserts are performed
>   into this container."

I tried using an arbitrary string like "ABCD" but that was no good. I tried a number of things to no good result.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Finally dug up an answer in this StackOverflow question:

[Active Directory Services: PrincipalContext -- What is the DN of a "container" object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538064/active-directory-services-principalcontext-what-is-the-dn-of-a-container-o)

Leave the thing at *null*.  Wow, what a concept.  I tried it and to my great surprise it actually worked.  Here's my final working code:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xxxdcoly302.xxx.xx.lcl", null, @"XXX\admin-acct", "Beautifu!"))
{
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userAccountID))
    {
        user.SetPassword("Pa$$word1");
        user.ExpirePasswordNow();
    }
}
```

Note that I first tried to include "LDAP://" as part of the server name above ("xxxdcoly302.xxx.xx.lcl").  This did not work!  It told me "The server could not be contacted."  I found another StackOverflow answer that said leave that LDAP prefix off.  So I did and it worked.