# Accessing the LDAP with PrincipalContext to a public server

Tags: c#, ldap, principalcontext

I am having issues connecting to a public LDAP using `PrincipalContext`. I can get directory entry working fine:

```
string sDomain = "LDAP://ldap.itd.umich.edu:389";
string sDefaultOU = "ou=System Groups,ou=Groups,dc=umich,dc=edu";
string sServiceUser = "cn=Directory Manager,o=University of Michigan,c=us";
string sServicePassword = "";

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(sDomain + "/" + sDefaultOU, sServiceUser, sServicePassword, AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
```

But when I try to do the same thing with `PrincipalContext` I get a null reference error:

```
sDomain = "ldap.itd.umich.edu";
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain, sDefaultOU, sServiceUser, "");
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this link help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538064/active-directory-services-principalcontext-what-is-the-dn-of-a-container-o

Comment: No, but thanks!  I am not trying to authenticate using AD credentials.  Technically i should only have to do this: PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain);

Comment: The new `PrincipalContext` only works against **Active Directory**, and my guess is this public LDAP server is not actually using AD.